# Linear Regression with Gradient Descent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, machine-learning

I'm coding a model of linear regression with gradient descent in JavaScript. I almost made it; there aren't errors, but something is wrong because the regression line isn't in the right position and after a while the line starts to go further from the points. I'm using the formulas from the Andrew's Ng Coursera course. What did I do wrong?

This is my code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
 width = canvas.width = 650,
 height = canvas.height = 650,
 stop = false;

let data;

let graph;
let n;
let off;

let theta;
let X,Y;
let alpha;

let timer;

setup();
draw();

function setup(){
 console.clear();
 console.log('ready');

 data = [];
 graph = false;
 n = 11;
 off = Math.floor(width/n);
 
 theta = [0,1];
 X = [];
 Y = [];
 alpha = 0.01;

 timer = 0;
 
};

function draw(){
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);

 grid(n,n);

 for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  let pos = getCoor(data[i]);
  arc(pos.x,pos.y,2);
  if(graph){
   if(data[i+1] != undefined){
    let pos1 = getCoor(data[i+1]);
    line(pos.x,pos.y,pos1.x,pos1.y);
   }
  }
 }

 if(timer % 50 == 0 && timer > 0){
  //console.log(J(X,Y,theta));
  console.log(theta);
 }

 if(data.length > 1){
  theta = GradientDescend(X,Y,theta,alpha);
  regLine();
 }

 timer++;

 if(!stop){
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
 };
};

if(stop){
 cancelAnimationFrame(draw);
};

function getCoor(data){
 let xx = data.x*width/n;
 let yy = height-data.y*height/n;

 return {x:xx,y:yy};
}

function regLine(){
 let m = theta[1];
 let b = theta[0];

 let x1 = 0;
 let y1 = height-m*x1+(b/11*width);
 let x2 = width;
 let y2 = height-m*x2+(b/11*width);

 line(x1,y1,x2,y2);
}

function grid(cx,cy){
 for(let d = 0; d < width; d+=off){
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
  stroke(0);
  line(d,0,d,height);
  line(0,d,width,d);
 }
};

document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
 let xx = (e.clientX/width)*n;
 let yy = (1-e.clientY/height)*n;

 data.push({x:xx,y:yy});

 X.push([1,xx]);
 Y.push(yy);
});

document.addEventListener("dblclick",function(e){
 graph = !graph;
});

document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
 if(e.keyCode == 32){
  data = [];
  X = [];
  Y = [];
 }
})

function h(X,theta){
 let y = 0;
 for(let i = 0; i < theta.length; i++){
  y += theta[i]*X[i];
 }

 return y;
};

function J(X,Y,theta){
 let m = Y.length;
 let sum = 0;

 for(let i = 0; i < m; i++){
  let err = h(X[i],theta)-Y[i];
  sum += err*err;
 }

 return sum/m;
}

function GradientDescend(X,Y,theta,alpha){
 let m = Y.length;
 let thetaTT = theta;
 for(let i = 0; i < m; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < thetaTT.length; j++){
   thetaTT[j] -= alpha*(1/m)*(h(X[i],thetaTT)-Y[i])*X[i][j];
  }
 }

 return thetaTT;
}

function arc(x, y, r,stroke){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
 if(stroke){
  ctx.stroke();
 }else{
  ctx.fill();
 }
}

function line(x, y, x1, y1){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(x, y);
 ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
 ctx.stroke();
}

function stroke(r,g,b,a){
 if(typeof r === 'string'){
  ctx.strokeStyle = r;
 }
 if(!a){
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
 }
 if(arguments.length == 1){
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb('+r+','+r+','+r+')';
 }
 if(arguments.length == 2){
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba('+r+','+r+','+r+','+g+')';
 }else{
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+','+a+')';
 }
}
```

```css
#canvas {
 background-color: #cccccc;
 width: 650px;
 height: 650px;
 position: absolute;
 border: solid #999999 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Where is the implementation of line and stroke?

Comment: @orabis I made some functions in an other file to make simpler to draw on the canvas.I didn't put these function in my question because I think that they aren't important to solve my problem

Comment: I would not be able to verify the behavior without running your code. The implementation of these functions will be helpful for me to have it running.

Comment: @orabis If this can help , I made a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fck638k4/

Comment: @GiuseppeRomeo, are m, b, x1, y1, x2, y2, your initial guesses? Are you trying to implement 2/n  n∑i=1  ((mx + b) - Actual)?